# JavaScript: How to display all divs until one gets selected

Tags: javascript, show-hide

This is what I want to achieve: If you chose one option only this single div should be displayed and the other ones are hidden.

For now only the div gets hidden which is selected and the others are shown. I can’t get behind why. This is my code I’m working on so far:

```js
    var DynDiv = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    function showSelected(sapna) {
        var t = 'dyndiv' + sapna,
            r, dv;
        for (var i = 0; i < DynDiv.length; i++) {
            r = 'dyndiv' + DynDiv[i];
            dv = document.getElementById(r);
            if (dv) {
                if (t === r) {
                    dv.style.display = 'none';
                } else {
                    dv.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Choose your flavor</h1>
    <select id="flavor" onchange="showSelected(this.value)">
        <option value="1">Sweet</option>
        <option value="2">Bitter</option>
        <option value="3">Salty</option>
        <option value="4">Umami</option>
    </select>

    <div id="dyndiv1" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div1</h3>
  <p>Sweet Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv2" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div2</h3>
  <p>Bitter Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv3" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div3</h3>
  <p>Salty Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv4" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div4</h3>
  <p>Umami Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for having a look at it!

Comment: Logic aside, I would suggest using more descriptive variable names, don't be afraid to use some characters, it will help future you understand what you wrote in the past and help other developers to read your code.

Comment: Agree with @Yoda, writing code like that makes it extremely hard to troubleshoot. In this case, I think you're literally just doing it backwards. You're saying `if (t === r) display: none`, that'll hide the div you've selected. If you swap `display: none` with `display: block` it should work, though this isn't really the best approach. Using a CSS class to hide and show won't mess with the display settings of your elements, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your feedback! I will do better next time in giving my variables more descriptive names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your logic reversed as you want to hide others which are not selected.

```
 if (t === r) {
    dv.style.display = 'block';
} else {
     dv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```js
var DynDiv = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    function showSelected(sapna) {
        var t = 'dyndiv' + sapna,
            r, dv;
        for (var i = 0; i < DynDiv.length; i++) {
            r = 'dyndiv' + DynDiv[i];
            dv = document.getElementById(r);
            if (dv) {
                if (t === r) {
                    dv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    dv.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Choose your flavor</h1>
    <select id="flavor" onchange="showSelected(this.value)">
        <option value="1">Sweet</option>
        <option value="2">Bitter</option>
        <option value="3">Salty</option>
        <option value="4">Umami</option>
    </select>

    <div id="dyndiv1" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div1</h3>
  <p>Sweet Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv2" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div2</h3>
  <p>Bitter Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv3" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div3</h3>
  <p>Salty Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
    <div id="dyndiv4" style="display:block;">
  <h3>Div4</h3>
  <p>Umami Lorem Ipsum</p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put the wrong condition.

**This the change in your code:**

```
if (t === r) {
    dv.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    dv.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

**Hope it helps!**

```js
var DynDiv = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);

function showSelected(sapna) {
  var t = 'dyndiv' + sapna,
    r, dv;
  for (var i = 0; i < DynDiv.length; i++) {
    r = 'dyndiv' + DynDiv[i];
    dv = document.getElementById(r);
    if (dv) {
      if (t === r) {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
      } else {

        dv.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Choose your flavor</h1>
  <select id="flavor" onchange="showSelected(this.value)">
        <option value="1">Sweet</option>
        <option value="2">Bitter</option>
        <option value="3">Salty</option>
        <option value="4">Umami</option>
    </select>

  <div id="dyndiv1" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div1</h3>
    <p>Sweet Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv2" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div2</h3>
    <p>Bitter Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv3" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div3</h3>
    <p>Salty Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv4" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div4</h3>
    <p>Umami Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing                     dv.style.display = 'none'; and                     dv.style.display = 'block';

```js
var DynDiv = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    function showSelected(sapna) {
        var t = 'dyndiv' + sapna,
            r, dv;
        for (var i = 0; i < DynDiv.length; i++) {
            r = 'dyndiv' + DynDiv[i];
            dv = document.getElementById(r);
            if (dv) {
                if (t === r) {
                    dv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    dv.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are 99% there... You just mixed up the CSS properties

```
if (t === r) {
    dv.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    dv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```js
var DynDiv = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);

function showSelected(sapna) {
  var t = 'dyndiv' + sapna,
    r, dv;
  for (var i = 0; i < DynDiv.length; i++) {
    r = 'dyndiv' + DynDiv[i];
    dv = document.getElementById(r);
    if (dv) {
      if (t === r) {
        dv.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        dv.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Choose your flavor</h1>
  <select id="flavor" onchange="showSelected(this.value)">
        <option value="1">Sweet</option>
        <option value="2">Bitter</option>
        <option value="3">Salty</option>
        <option value="4">Umami</option>
    </select>

  <div id="dyndiv1" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div1</h3>
    <p>Sweet Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv2" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div2</h3>
    <p>Bitter Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv3" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div3</h3>
    <p>Salty Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dyndiv4" style="display:block;">
    <h3>Div4</h3>
    <p>Umami Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</body>
```